# SonarQube server won't start

Tags: maven, sonarqube

I've been using SonarQube for a year now and once I had been through all the installation process, I never got any problem... Until now.

I'm just trying to analyze a Maven Project (like I did several times before). To do so, I need to run the server first (port 9000). But when I launch "StartSonar.bat" (I'm on Windows), I get a huge log and finally the wrapper stops.

I think there is something wrong with the port 9000 although I'm not sure because I'm not that advanced with analysing logs and everything.

[Here's a link to download the log I get](http://www.filedropper.com/sonar)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The log states "Address already in use: bind" which means that some other tool already runs on that port. Choose another one should already do the trick.
Or there is a zombie-process still running (no clean shutdown). But you should see a process in the task manager - just kill that one. Usually a reboot should solve that too.

Answer (score 0):

Run `netstat -abo` on the Windows command line to see which ports are used, by which programs they are used and their process IDs (PID). With the PID you can find the process in Task Manager and kill it there if necessary.